# Problem signing in via Google Drive API in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Within my app I use the Google Drive API to access the files of the selected account. Everything works correctly with different accounts that I use, but now if I create a new google account and log in with it through my app, it cannot view the files saved in the account or upload new ones. The strange thing is that it only happens with new accounts created, with old ones I have no problem. Has anything changed in Google policies? Do I have to give further permissions via the myaccount control panel? In the security section I see that my app is authorized to read and write files on Google Drive.